# Java inner class access variable in another inner class

Tags: java, class

My main Class has 2 inner class, 1 of them is thread, I don't know how my inner class 2 can access (Or how to know var1 is true or false) value of inner class 1, this is my example, thanks!

```
public class InnerClass  {
    public class InnerClass1 implements NativeKeyListener {
        public boolean var1;
    }

    public class InnerClass2 implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                var1...
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You would need an instance of `InnerClass1`.

Comment: Anyway can do it!

Comment: I'm sorry, come again?

Comment: and why would you need those two inner classes to begin with ?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, are you sure you didn't mix something up?

Comment: You do need an instance of class1, because the `var1` inside class1 would be created until the instance of class1 is created.

Comment: I just edited it, please take a look

Comment: How is your edit relevant to anything?

Comment: Can InnerClass2 access variable of InnerClass?

Comment: @FesNguyen yes you can do it through a third class or interface. Try my code on answer section.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access nonstatic variables/methods/inner classes unless you have instantiated the object (i.e. [created an instance of the object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)).  You need an `InnerClass1` object before you can store or get anything out of it.  Until you do something like `InnerClass1 foo = new InnerClass1()`, there is no `var1` anywhere.

Anyway, I think you are misusing inner classes.  I'd suggest if you haven't already walking through the [Java Tutorials Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html) to get a basic idea of how classes, fields, and instantiation work in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by an interface or class that is implemented by innerclass1. Try this:

```
public interface NativeKeyListener {
boolean a();
}

public class InnerClass {

static NativeKeyListener m() {
    class InnerClass1 implements NativeKeyListener {
        public boolean var1;

        public boolean a() {
            return var1;
        }
    }
    return new InnerClass1();
}

public class InnerClass2 implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        NativeKeyListener i = InnerClass.m();
        i.a();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: if you don't want to add method `a()` on interface `NativeKeyListener` then create a new `interface` with method def like `a()` and implement it on `InnerClass1`. On that case `NativeKeyListener i = InnerClass.m();` will become `NewInterface i = InnerClass.m();`